# Laravel - Fatal error HTML Facade is Defered error

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

Trying to install the fresh copy of Laravel, and I am having the below error

**FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 119: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::isDeferred()**

**Composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
```

**app.php**

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,


],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,

],
```

Comment: I'm confused. This is the `Illuminate\Html` provider but that's been deprecated for quite some time. Also, you tagged `Laravel 5.1` but you show `5.2.*`. Please tell us how you performed the installation?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i did it via `composer create-project`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use laravel collective:
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

It is where Form and HTML besides now.